# Can't open docx in sharepoint, IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, docx, internet-explorer-11

On our intranet we can't open docx-files on IE11. Chrome works just fine just as Firefox.

Browsers that fail:

- IE11

Browsers that succeed:

- Chrome
- Firefox

Error in Console

> SCRIPT5: Access is denied. File: wordviewerframe.aspx, Line: 1,
>   Column: 1

Error while opening file with developer tools open:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'selectSingleNode'

Does anyone know this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just a tip - there is a sharepoint specific site at stack exchange: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com. It's not wrong to post SharePoint questions here, but I think you will get better answers there ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing all the updates did it for me.